# How to use a variable inside a string

Tags: javascript

I can take value of a span with this code:

```
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:0:asd").innerHTML
```

but I want to use variable like `i=1`, for example like this:

```
i=1
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:'[i]':asd").innerHTML
```

but it gives an error. How can I use the `i` variable in the string?

Comment: What is the error, what have you tried so far?

Comment: ı mean as a error ı couldnt get value of span 
ı tried
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:'[i]':asd").innerHTML
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:"[i]":asd").innerHTML
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:'[i]':asd").value
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:'[i]':asd").val
and etc like that in console

Comment: Don't consider me to be rude but your knowledge of JavaScript is too low. You will have the more difficulties the farther you go if you don't try to learn the language.

Comment: ı know what u mean unfortunately u are right but ı dont use javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:"+ i +":asd").innerHTML
```

Note the change I made inside. `"+ i +"` . You actually needed a **String Concatenation**.

So explaining the code.

when `i = 1`

`"aaa:j_idt89:"+ i +":asd"` = `"aaa:j_idt89:"+ 1 +":asd"` = `"aaa:j_idt89:1:asd"` = `thats what you need`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var i = 1;
var element = document.getElementById("aaa:j_idt89:" + i + ":asd").innerHTML
```

you need to build your string up and to use your variable you need to concatenate it to your string like above `" + i + "` and it will work.

Comment: ha just in time @Reddy

Comment: great please mark the answer as accepted to which ever answer out of mine and @Reddy helped you the most as their both correct :)

Comment: ı will do in 3 minutes:)

Comment: Both reached a milestone :) +1 from my side.